# Slick Slider—Mobile Only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a slick slider with my cards only on the phone screen.

And I've done most of it. The problem is that when I switch from the big screen to the phone size, the slick doesn't work, but if I render it, it starts working. What is the reason for this?

My card codes and slick codes are in the link.

[image]

I want the slider to work without rendering when I switch from computer size to phone size.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please [do not upload images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) in your question. Instead use the available tools in StackOverflow so the community may better help you. You may also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better prepare your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Keep in mind the phrase, "it doesn't work" encompasses pretty much any issue ranging from console warnings to the Chernobyl nuclear meltdown. Because of this it isn't particularly helpful when debugging, what exactly happens as you switch to the phone screen? What did the card look like before? What does it look like after? What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
responsive: [
        {
           breakpoint: 480,
           settings: "unslick"
        }
     ]
```